# Flowplayer question mark

Tags: flowplayer

How can I add a file with a question mark to flowplayer?

I need something like this:

```
http://maindomain.dev/file.flv?a=someparameter&b=secondparameter
```

if I add a link to flowplayer does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A question mark URL encodes as `%3F`. But you should use a proper encoder for the whole thing rather than manually encoding a specific character.

Depending on the server-side technology you're using to build the Urls, tyhere should be a function like `UrlEncode()` which should handle all this for you. Failing that, Javascript has `encodeUriComponent()`

Comment: Glad I could help. See this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3608791/156755 - You're encoding a parameter so should use `encodeUriComponent()`